# Sketch a graph that satisfies the following conditions

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

> Sketch the graph of an example of a function f(x) that satisfies all of the following conditions:
>   [image]

Here is what I have so far:
[image]

**Am I on the right track?** I think the graph satisfies all of the conditions, but the lines cross at about (2,3)- is that acceptable? I know there are probably a large number of ways to draw this, is there a better way I should be aware of?

### EDIT #1

[image]

How does this look? **Does the graph now satisfy the conditions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to mark the asymptotic points at $(0,-2)$ and $(0,1)$:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While, you catches all of the conditions, except #3, which is at $(0,-1)$, which is an isolated point.

But your plot has multiple y values for $x \in (0,2)$, which is not right.

What you should do is:

Connect $(2^+, -\infty)$ to $(+\infty, 3)$.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Please see edit.

Comment: Put a black point at $(0,-1)$